# pass several parameters in Django rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am new with `Django` and `Django rest framework`, I try to create several routes to get the data from the database.

Right now  in my `urls.py` file I have this

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'cpuProjects', cpuProjectsViewSet, base_name='cpuProjects'),
```

this return this

```
"cpuProjects": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/cpuProjects/"
```

and I have the possibility to do this 
 `http://127.0.0.1:8000/cpuProjects/`  => return all project
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/cpuProjects/ad` => return a particular project.

In my view.py I have this

```
class cpuProjectsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
  serializer_class = serializers.cpuProjectsSerializer
  # lookup_field = 'project_name'
  lookup_url_kwarg = 'project_name'

  def list(self, request):
    all_rows = connect_database()
    serializer = serializers.cpuProjectsSerializer(instance=all_rows, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

  def retrieve(self, request, project_name=None):
    try:
      opc = {'name_proj' : project_name }
      all_rows = connect_database(opc)
    except KeyError:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    except ValueError:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    serializer = serializers.cpuProjectsSerializer(instance=all_rows, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Now I want that my Url accepted something like that

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/cpuProjects/ad/comments`
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/cpuProjects/ad/ussing`
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/cpuProjects/ad/process`

For this I add this new url

```
router.register(r'cpuProjects/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$', cpuProjectsViewSet, base_name='cpuProjects'),
```

but now when I try this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/cpuProjects/ad/ussing
```

I obtain "page no found"

I understood that this URL have to call to retrieve function to get the parameters, so, why this error?

This URL don't do the same process like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/cpuProjects/ad
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat similar to what we did in our earlier [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39729388/using-django-rest-framework-to-return-info-by-name/39736838#39736838)

```
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route, list_route
@detail_route(url_path='(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<what>[\w-]+)')
def get_by_name(self, request, pk=None,slug=None, what=None):
    print(slug, what)
```

Similarly you can do the same for a `list_route`

Answer (score 0):

The routers framework isn't meant to be used with several parameters .. you can manually do it with primary keys (in the regular expressions).