# django rest framework: Get url path variable in a view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have to pass the `product_id` (which is a string) into a view. There I have to do some DB operations based on the product id. How can I get that product id in that view? Actually what should be the parameter in the class `ProductDetailConfiguration` view? Now I am passing `viewsets.ModelViewSet`. Actually, this API call is not completely related to any model.

**# urls.py**

```
  url(r'^product-configuration/(?P<product_id>[\w-]+)/$', views.ProductDetailConfiguration, name='product-configuration'),
```

**# views.py**

```
class ProductDetailConfiguration(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Product.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
      
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        product_id = self.request.get('product_id', None)
        #filter query set based on the product_id
        return queryset

    serializer_class = ProductConfigurationSerializer
```

Answer (score 25):

The URL parameters are available in `self.kwargs`.
From [the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-url):

> ## Filtering against the URL
>
> Another style of filtering might involve restricting the queryset based on some part of the URL.
>
> For example if your URL config contained an entry like this:
>
> ```
> url('^purchases/(?P<username>.+)/$', PurchaseList.as_view()),
> ```
>
> You could then write a view that returned a purchase queryset filtered by the username portion of the URL:
>
> ```
> class PurchaseList(generics.ListAPIView):
>    serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer
>
>    def get_queryset(self):
>        """
>        This view should return a list of all the purchases for
>        the user as determined by the username portion of the URL.
>        """
>        username = self.kwargs['username']
>        return Purchase.objects.filter(purchaser__username=username)
> ```

Comment: self.kwargs['param'] -> this is the right answer

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `lookup_field` in your views to get `product_id` and the view should not belongs to any model. Here I already answer a question like yours [using django rest framework to return info by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39729388/using-django-rest-framework-to-return-info-by-name/39731786#39731786)

Hope this will help to solve your problem.

Comment: I have implemented like you suggested in that question. When I print the queryset in view it shows the result. `ProductConfigurationCustomSerializer(queryset)`. Then what should be the model in serializer. When I commented the model references it throws error.

Comment: Actually,  what do you want to do? In your question, you just asked for getting product_id in views.

Answer (score 0):

#### This is my approach:

Update URL:

```
url(r'^product-configuration$', views.ProductDetailConfiguration, name='product-configuration'),
```

In view.py:

```
class ProductDetailConfiguration(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'product_id'
    serializer_class = ProductConfigurationSerializer

    def retrieve(request, product_id=None, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        # Filter with produc_id
        # print(product_id)
        # Return Response
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the data from the request url by  :-
 `data_dict = self.request.data`
This will return a dictionary of all the parameters of the request url.
You can use the parameter name as the key

Comment: URL parameters are not in there.